# clearing the notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to clear all the notification present in my device, notifications from other apps also.

I tried using:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(TestActivity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
```

but of no good. Whereas in another test from where i am sending notifications this code works.

Is it not permitted to delete notifications from other applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cancel notifications from other apps-  its done that way to prevent malicious apps from hiding other applications.

Comment: but can i do it after a time interval?

Comment: No.  Only notifications from your own app